# hide the last column from gridview by asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview

I need ask question, How can hide last column from GridView?
The GridView has data from file xml. the last column is id

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            refreshdata();
        }

    }

    public void refreshdata()
    {
        DataSet dsg = new DataSet();
        dsg.ReadXml(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + website/hotal/WebsitesFound.xml");
        GridView1.DataSource = dsg;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `GridView1.Columns[GridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Visible = false;`

Comment: The column hidden is check

Comment: delete it from the xml file - you know that what you ask is leading to a bad design....